# Error: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'

Tags: flutter, gradle, version

After starting a new Flutter project, I wanted to work with Firebase in my project, I added following to the project:

- `firebase_core` and `firebase_auth` to the ***pubspec.yaml***
- ***google-services.json*** to the corresponding path
- `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.6'` to ***android/build.gradle***
- `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.0')` to the **"dependencies"** in the ***app/build.gradle***

Until now everything works well, but after adding this line to the ***app/build.gradle :***

- `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

After adding this line and even without editing the application code, I got the following error message:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\1337\StudioProjects\teest\android\build.gradle' line: 27
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method setVariantDir() for arguments [debug] on task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' of type com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This is my ***android/build.gradle***

```
buildscript {...}
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.6'
    }
}
allprojects {...}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {... }
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
task clean(type: Delete) {...}
```

Ps: by running `flutter doctor -v` is everything fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing:

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.6'`

to

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'`

in `android/build.gradle`.

If they still fail for you then make sure that you are using the latest update of android SDK, android studio, flutter SDK, Gradle version, and project dependencies.

Also, let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hey!, thanks a lot for your answer, the version 4.3.5 isn't functionning too. I tried instead with the version 4.0.0 and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. As of now, I'm using version 4.3.5 and I was able to recreate the issue in version 4.3.5. But I also tried the latest version 4.3.8 and it is also working fine for me. So, I have updated my answer to make sure everything is correct on your side.

Comment: I just tried with the 4.3.8 and it's working fine, thanks for letting me know.
As I created yesterdey a new project, the latest version was 4.3.6 so i copied the line as it was in the website.